# How to pass encryption related properties from tomcat's context.xml for jdbc connection in java?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, sybase, bouncycastle

We have an application developed in struts2. The application server used is Weblogic. We are using Sybase ASE database. We are using plain JDBC to connect to database.

Recently we turned the encryption on in weblogic server. So we added 3 properties

```
key="ENCRYPT_PASSWORD" value="true"

key="JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS" value="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider"

key="RETRY_WITH_NO_ENCRYPTION" value="true"
```

The weblogic server is used in PROD environment. In weblogic, it is working fine. But we do local development using tomcat 7.0. In tomcat, we are using context.xml with following tags.

```
<Resource name="CONN.DS" auth="Container"      
   type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
   username="abc" 
   password="dfg"      
     driverClassName="com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver"    
      url="jdbc:sybase:Tds:xyz:1234/DbName"      
        maxActive="10" maxIdle="4"/>
```

To get connection in java, we use below code,

```
javax.sql.Datasource ds = null;
try{


            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
              ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("CONN.DS");

}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

return ds.getConnection();
```

Actually in weblogic, by adding above 3 properties, it is working fine. But in tomcat, we use context.xml. So how can we pass above three properties through context.xml while taking a connection in eclipse and tomcat?

At present, at line '`ds.getConnection()`', it is giving error :

```
'An exception occurred: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException'

    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following connection string:

```
jdbc:sybase:Tds:xyz:1234/DbName?ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true&JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider&RETRY_WITH_NO_ENCRYPTION=true
```

Also, check http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0700/html/prjdbc0700/X32549.htm

Comment: This did not worked as it is giving following error : Could not load the context configuration for the <project-context-name> context due to a syntax error or other exception.
The reference to entity "JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS" must end with the ';' delimiter. I also replaced & with ';' but still not working.

Comment: When I replaced '&' with ';', it is giving error : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (JZ011: Format exception encountered while parsing connection property ENCRYPT_PASSWORD.)

Comment: If this configuration string is inside an XML file, you must replace `&` with `&amp;`, so it would become `jdbc:sybase:Tds:xyz:1234/DbName?ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true&amp;JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider&amp;RETRY_WITH_NO_ENCRYPTION=true`

Comment: This answer was very helpful